# CSS3 transition/animation for div added/removed/style changed?

Tags: html, css, transition

Is there a way to have CSS3 transitions/animations for a div that's just been added to/removed from the window or just has its style assigned? One scenario would be a tab control where the content has transitions when a tab header is clicked; this is normally done by assigning a different CSS style to the div that contains the content (without transition) that you want to display:

```
    tabs-content > div{display:none;}
    tabs-content > div.active{display:block;}
```

It occurred to me that most of the examples out there are using CSS3 transitions triggered by :hover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS can't be triggered like that. You'll have to use JavaScript to either add a class to that element and let CSS animate it (I doubt it will work), or animate it directly with JavaScript.

I'd choose the latter.

Comment: [example (non selector)](https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/cssref/transitions/sample1/)

Comment: Basically the idea is to have 2 styles (you need to explicitly set the properties you want to animate in each style) and assign the style to begin your animation with to the target element. Then in page load, you listen to the "transitionend" event for the element, at which point you assign the style you want your animation to end with. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
tabs-content > div{
    opacity:0;
    -moz-opacity:0;
    -webkit-opacity:0;
    transition-duration:1s;
    -moz-transition-duration:1s;
    -webkit-transition-duration:1s;
}
tabs-content:active > div{
    opacity:1;
    -moz-opacity:1;
    -webkit-opacity:1;
}
```

You can see this live on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kongr45gpen/7J2M6/).

Comment: If you don't want *click & hold down*, you can either hover or use jQuery. Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/kongr45gpen/7J2M6/4/

Comment: Thanks for the code. I think you are using selector ("hover/link/active/visited") for the existing span; I see that triggers the transitions. My question was if it's possible to trigger a transition when you add/delete/swap styles for an element.

Answer (score 1):

**For transitions/animations:** I would use jQuery because you can delegate events to elements that may not have been created yet. You also have more control and if you add/remove elements using jQuery then you can add animation at the same time.

css:

```
.elementInactive {
    display:none;
}
```

jquery:

```
$('tabs-content > div').hover(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('elementInactive');
});
```

**For swapping one style with another (not an animation):**  I would use css' `:hover` property. Support for this property dates back long before CSS3, so it is a safe solution. IE has problems with using a 'div' element with :hover, so use an 'a' element with display:block to treat it like a div:

css:

```
tabs-content > a:hover {display:block;}
tabs-content > a {display:none;}
```